# What happens if my initial rating is below 1000?

Tags: elo

If I were to play 5 FIDE rated games against players rated 1000 and I scored half a point in all of them;

1. Will my FIDE rating still be calculated but shown as unrated?
2. What happens if I play more games and my FIDE rating is still less than 1000?

Comment: Is this a FIDE rating, or a national federation? You may want to [edit the question](https://chess.stackexchange.com/posts/42862/edit) to add the appropriate tag.

Answer (score 2):

FIDE rating floor was raised to 1400 on  [1. March 2024](https://www.fide.com/news/2831).

If your first rating is under rating floor, or if your rating drops under 1400, you are unrated. Relevant parts of [rating regulations](https://handbook.fide.com/chapter/B022024):

> 7.1.4      A rating for a player new to the list shall be published when it is based on at least 5 games against rated opponents. This need not be met in one tournament. Results from other tournaments played within consecutive rating periods of not more than 26 months are pooled to obtain the initial rating. The rating must be at least 1400.

> 7.2.1      Players whose ratings drop below 1400 are shown as unrated on the next list. Thereafter they are treated in the same manner as any other unrated player.

So games will be used for calculation of your first rating, as long as they were played less than 26 months before you got rating, even if you performed under rating floor. As long as your performance stays under rating floor you won't get rated.

Answer (score 0):

according to [FIDE rules](https://handbook.fide.com/chapter/B022017) , if you have scored more than zero in a rated tournament , then your results will affect your FIDE rating even if it doesn't get published (as it is below 1000)

Hope this helps!

Comment: so can i know what my rating is even if it is not published

Comment: you can use FIDE rating calculation to figure it out